# Is it a good practice to throw an exception on Validate() methods or better to return bool value?

Tags: c#, java, exception, validation

Is it recommended or not to throw exceptions from Validation methods like:

```
ValidateDates();
ValidateCargoDetails();
```

Apart from this : Is there a robust validation design pattern often used?

Answer (score 33):

I would suggest returning a ValidationResult object containing ValidationFailures.
You should never use exceptions as part of your logical coding.  Exceptions are for exceptions

Comment: Shouldn't validation failures be exceptional?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey - In my experience, users entering invalid data is the rule, not the exception.

Comment: Ayende seems to agree with @Andrew on this. Have a look here: [What is wrong with this api](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/11/12/what-is-wrong-with-this-api.aspx) and it's [answer](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/11/13/what-is-wrong-with-this-api-answer.aspx). You may also want to read the entire discussion.

Comment: @Jarrett, I think alot depends on what you are validating and what action you need to take for a failure.  Exceptions are not useful for users, they want friendly descriptions of what they should have done.  However exceptions are useful if you need to stop processing, and a friendly message which could be ignored is dangerous.

Comment: @Peter - Sorry, I was attempting some humor, but it must have been lost in the arial font. For the record, I 100% agree that returning a collection of failures at the UI level (and displaying them nicely) is far better than throwing an exception.

Comment: @Jarrett, I would agree that you should always assume that a user might enter the unexpected if not the accidently malicious values. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: In deciding whether something should be an exception, the best question is "Is the *immediate calling code* expected to deal with the condition?" Throw an exception if it isn't. The very fact that code is calling a validation routine suggests pretty strongly that the code is prepared to deal with the possibility of failure.  It's not a 100% implication--the caller may not be prepared to do anything other than fail with an exception, but may have called the routine avoid undertaking an action that would fail later--but it would favor use of error return codes vs exceptions.

Comment: I really don't know where this rule is coming from.  If an operation fails, for whatever reason, to me that's an exception.  I mean, we have things such as invalid parameter exceptions.  How is an invalid data exception any different?  In a REST environment, I would think it would make more sense to return a 400 error and embed the validation results in JSON.  Isn't this considered an exception in JavaScript?  It will hit your AJAX error handler.  By using ValidationResult, you're forced to pollute all of your public methods with that type, whether they actually use validation or not.

Answer (score 21):

I would say it all depends on what/how you are doing the validation.  But at the end of the day a developer can always choose to ignore a returned result (this is the problem with them), they can't ignore an exception without writing explicit code to do so.

Comment: Why did this get -1? Everything I just said is fact not opinion

Answer (score 18):

I usually use `visitor pattern` for validating input; accumulating all the errors into a list or something to show the user. The logic goes like, checking the list for validation errors, if found, inform the user, otherwise good to go.

IMO, validation errors are not something exceptional, hence it should not be dealt like one.

Answer (score 6):

Throwing exception must **not** be used to *control the flow of the application*. As the name implies, it happens in **exceptional** cases while validation could commonly fail. They are also **expensive** and impact the performance.

I would go with returning a **boolean plus a string for reason**.

Comment: How can you return a boolean **plus** a string? :)

Comment: @yegor256 I would wrap them in a class or **exceptionally** use `out`.

Comment: Why/When do you prefer wrapping them in a class over using `out`?

Comment: @BornToCode Using "out" is a terrible idea (unless you really have to - I havent used out for years).  C# is supposed to be an OO language so create a class.

Comment: @bytedev use value tuples instead

Comment: @DeepakMishra I think you have missed my point.

Answer (score 5):

Alot depends on how exceptional validation failures are are how critical it is to be correct.

If your validation failures are rare and severe or fatal when they occur, I would use Exceptions or even AssertionErrors.  Most parsers use Exceptions and these indicate it is not possible to continue processing.

If your validation failure are expected as under normal operations and do not indicate you cannot continue processing, I would suggest using a visitor pattern or return a List of issues (which can be empty)

Comment: can yo please point me to any example which explain your answer in details.

Comment: @Rumel BufferedReader.readLine() return `null` when there is no more data, which is an expected outcome, however if there is an error, an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

Users entering invalid data is the very definition of an exception. When writing business requirements for a solution you always write the non-error paths as the main flow and error paths as exceptional paths. Using exceptions for validation is perfectly acceptable. Validating with exceptions also allows you to prioritise the order in how they are handled and to handle the error differently depending on what level you are at in the architecture stack (a string describing the error is of little use at the Data Access Layer).

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I'm quite on the fence on all of this. Sometimes I'm also building a visitor pattern, but it really feels I'm just re-implementing Exceptions.

What I definitely don't like about the visitor pattern is that if your six levels deep and you notice that you need to break off you *have* to check the result at every level above.

It means a lot of boilerplate code that actually can introduce bugs.

**Example**
What if you checked `A` - it doesn not validate, but the code continues checking `B` that actually depends on a proper initialized `A`? In complicated validation logic this can happens on a lot of different paths. It is error prone.

On the other hand I used (custom) `ValidationExceptions` and haven't come across any significant problems. You hit something that does not validate and you are ensured that all the other validation logic will be skipped. This is a big win for simplicity of code.

*"Throwing exception must not be used to control the flow of the application."* - for 99% of the other cases I would agree, but hanging on to this for validation logic seems to me based on dogma, not on pragmatism.

**About performace:**
Performance reasons are 99% not a concern in validation logic for user input, as this is almost never is done in tight loops.

**Summary:** I recommend ignoring the *"Exceptions are for Exceptional things"* dogma, create (custom!) Exceptions that you throw and catch on the top level and see if it works for you. For me it does.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to bring this into the picture, answer of RADZSERG to the blog: [Why throwing exceptions is better than returning error codes](http://javierferrer.me/exceptions-vs-error-codes/).

In short - we do not need to limit ourselves to use boolean as a return type...

> I’m not telling that we should use or not to use Exception
>
> but as for that specific article – you build bad code at the beginning then tries to make it better. Build good code at the beginning and the explain why it’s better when we use exception.
>   Here’s my example
>
> ```
> class TooManyLoginAttempts extends ValidationError{}
>
> if ($hasTooManyLoginAttempts) {
>     return new TooManyLoginAttempts()
> }
> ...
> $validationResult = $this->validate();
> if ($validationResult instanceof ValidationError) {
>     $this->errorLogger->log($validationResult->getMessage());
> }
> ```
>
> it also solves all described problems
>   – no magic numbers
>   – we’re solving the problem of having the error code across our entire application
>   – my code is much shorter and also follows open-close principle

I came here from: [Is it a good practice to throw an exception on Validate() methods or better to return bool value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230978/is-it-a-good-practice-to-throw-an-exception-on-validate-methods-or-better-to-r/59785532#59785532) which is locked.