# If Validation methods should return a validation result, why there is ArgumentException class?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, exception, argumentexception

I am a bit confused.

What MSDN says for ArgumentException is:

> "The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a
>   method is not valid."

So I would throw an exception if the passed arguments to my method are not valid.

But also I found out that it is suggested to return boolean plus a string for reason. -instead of throwing an exception.

So,

**Question** : When validationg method parameters, and when the parameters are not valid, when should the Validation method throw an exception and when it should not?

Comment: "it is suggested to return boolean plus a string for reason" It would help to cite where you read this, with a link.

Comment: for example...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230978/is-it-a-good-practice-to-throw-an-exception-on-validate-methods-or-better-to-r

Comment: How is your previous question different from this one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a method whose purpose it is to validate its arguments (for example: is this a valid username/password combination), by all means return a bool (false = invalid) plus a reason. Do not throw an exception for an expected situation (if it's not expected, why validate?)

The situation is different if you have a "Process" method: there you must have valid parameters, so it is reasonable to throw an exception (stating the problem) when they are invalid.

Comment: +1 Agree. However, if you need to return a bool with a string IMO you should return a class that encapsulates the bool and string together.  Don't use output params, they just lead to a headache when someone comes to maintain/refactor your code.

Comment: @nashwan: An advantage of having a class to encapsulate the failure cause is that it may be possible to have derived classes include more information applicable to certain types of failures.