# Is throwing exceptions on argument validation in an API considered a good practice?

Tags: c#, function, exception

Is it regarded as a good practice to throw an exception on function argument verification, as I do with the TryPassNameValidation function, if:

1. The code is not facing directly towards the UI. It is part of an API.
2. It is critical that execution doesn't continue with a wrong argument.
3. I want good readability and flow.

I have also considered returning a validation object, like described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5231015/2741982) but this style of programming reminds me of the way [GoLang functions handle errors](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go). I thought that exceptions were invented to prevent us having to do that.

```
    public void AddChildStructureLevel(Structure childStructureLevel)
    {
        try
        {
            TryPassNameValidation(childStructureLevel.Name); // throws if something is wrong
            Children.Add(childStructureLevel);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ae)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Provided structure name {childStructureLevel.Name} is invalid.", ae);
        }

        Trace.WriteLine($"Added new child structure level to parent structure children.");
    }

    private void TryPassNameValidation(string structureName)
    {
        TryPassingStructureNameMinMaxLength(structureName); 
        TryPassingStructureNameUnique(structureName);
    }

    private void TryPassingStructureNameMinMaxLength(string structureName)
    {
        bool nameIsTooLong  = structureName.Length >= maxLengthStructureName;
        bool nameIsTooShort = structureName.Length <= minLengthStructureName;

        if (nameIsTooLong) throw new ArgumentException($"Structure name is too long. Max {maxLengthStructureName} characters.");
        if (nameIsTooShort) throw new ArgumentException($"Structure name is too short. Min {minLengthStructureName} characters.");
    }

    private void TryPassingStructureNameUnique(string childName)
    {
        foreach (Structure child in Children) //TODO: recurse over children.children
            if (child.Name == childName) throw new ArgumentException($"Structure level name {childName} already exists.");
    }
```

Comment: I think http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the better place to ask.

Comment: Yes, although in the end everything remains somewhat opinion-based. Your use case however describes the exact conditions an exception would be used at by most developers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Valentin. Didn't even know it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this code hard to understand which is contrary to your goals. The validation is done through nested calls and non-obvious control flow (exceptions). I find the usual `if ... throw;` sequence at the beginning of each method much easier to understand. In part because almost all validation code looks like that.

`TryPassingStructureNameUnique` should be written using `Any`. After doing that it fits on one line and can be used in the mentioned `if ... throw;` validation pattern.

The `bool nameIsTooLong` thing is really verbose. These conditions are trivial. They should just use the `if ... throw;` pattern.

Besides that I think this design is a valid choice. It's not an easy choice. I would not do it like that if I could help it.

If validity is such a core concept for you consider wrapping each `Structure` in a `ValidatedStructure` wrapper class. Validate on construction. That way you know from visual inspection whether a given `Structure` is validated already or not.

Comment: I don't validate on construction because the new Structure has to validate against the Structure, which it is being added to. So I have to validate it when I add it. About the nested calls - I am trying to have one function do one thing. Agree with the rest.

Comment: This "one thing per function" rule is not very good because it is undefined what a thing is. Is the computation `structureName.Length >= maxLengthStructureName` not one thing?! So split it off! (Not serious.) The one-thing rule is totally bogus. It is a bad proxy for some real issues such as understandability and clean interfaces.

Comment: Often source code describes a routine better than a name would, agree. With the maxNameLength checks I need to have the functionality separate though. I also use the function to validate the arguments for DeleteChildWithName before I iterate over all structure children.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by API.

If you mean a piece of business logic where you can predict an invalid input like empty user name then I wouldn't throw any exceptions.

If you however mean a piece of framework (a library shared across the team) where you want to indicate its invalid usage to the user because the API cannot work with invalid parameters then I would throw an exception.