# What exception to use when at least one of many values must be non null?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an API that requires one of two types of input. The first is that is has value A but not X, and the second is that it has X but not A. I am writing a validation method and am stuck on what kind of exception to throw if neither exist.

In the case that they both exist, I throw an Argument Exception

```
throw new ArgumentException("Cannot contain both A and X");
```

The scenario I am stuck on is in the event that neither A nor X are given. I would think to throw some sort of ArgumentNullException, but would not know which parameter to specify as in theory either one provided would be fine and I do not want to confuse the user of the method too much by giving only one.

**What kind of exception is appropriate to throw when one of 2 values is mandatory, and neither are given?**

TIA

**EDIT - Adding some additional details**

The API is what my function will be calling. This class handles receiving the model from whomever calls it (there are multiple potential callers from within the service). After receiving the model, it runs a validation check before converting to the API and sending it on.

Comment: Writing a [custom exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions) is really simple

Comment: Agreed with @Steve - you don't have to necessarily use an inbuilt exception to be thrown, you can make your custom Exception class (derived from standard .NET `Exception` class) & use it for this scenario.

Comment: Well, the exception will probably not be automatically resolvable anyways and the message is merely for the developer using your API to help solve the problem. So you should care for a proper explanation in the exception message. For instance `throw new ArgumentException("Either A or X are required")`. Or you might also use an `new ArgumentNullException("One of the parameters is required", "A, X")` where the second argument of the constructor names the respective parameters.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a lot of detail here but I believe this discussion from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230978/is-it-a-good-practice-to-throw-an-exception-on-validate-methods-or-better-to-r) will get you thinking about this in the right way. The short answer is if you are going raise exceptions they would likely be validation exceptions.

When it comes to API's if you're raising validation exceptions, commonly you do so with the intention of catching them and returning a validation error message. Some will suggest it is better to cut out the middle step, and never raise an exception an instead design returning validation error responses into your API without raising exceptions at all.